# Don't show dropdown in Autocompletebox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocompletebox

I get response from server, it is Json where are data about street names. Then I parse response string to Json, and add street names to list. I want that this list show like dropdown in Autocompletebox, when text length equals two(I press second character in Autocompletebox). 
Also I use Json.Net library.
I use this code:

Here is class(JsonWorker) I use:

```
class JsonWorker
    {

        public async Task<HttpWebResponse> send(string requestUrl, JObject jsonObjesct)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            request.Method = "POST";

            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonObjesct.ToString());

            Stream x = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            await x.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
            x.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) (await request.GetResponseAsync());
            return response;
        }

        public async Task<string> get(
            HttpWebResponse response)
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string str_responsefromjson = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();

            return str_responsefromjson;

        }
```

Here is method(GetSteets):

```
private async Task<List<string>> GetStreets()
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("chars", AutoCompleteBox_Streets.Text);
        jo.Add("city_id", "1");

        JsonWorker jWorker = new JsonWorker();
        var response = await jWorker.send("website", jo);
        string str_responseformjson = await jWorker.get(response);

        jo = JObject.Parse(str_responseformjson);


        JArray ja = (JArray)jo["street"];


        List<string> list_Streets = new List<string>();


        foreach (var elem in ja)
        {

            list_Streets.Add(elem["title"].ToString());
        }


        return list_Streets;
    }
```

Here is when I call the method above:

```
private async void AutoCompleteBox_Streets_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AutoCompleteBox_Streets.Text.Length.Equals(2))
            {
                AutoCompleteBox_Streets.ItemsSource = await GetStreets(); 
                //On the string of code above in debug, ItemSource contains list of streets
            }
        }
```

And when I enter the second character in Autocompletebox, it don't show dropdownlist. Please help.

Comment: Also, if I change FilterMode to Contains, it starts show drop down when I enter 3 or 4 characters. Some magic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

After understanding your use case then what you need is use the `Populating` event. This event is fired when you want to populate the drop-down with possible matches. To make this called once 2 characters or more have been typed you will also need to set `MinimumPrefixLength` to 2.

Moreover, change your `GetStreets` method to take a `string` param containing the chars in the textbox.

```cs
// Your page Loaded event. Bind this event in your xaml.
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  AutoCompleteBox_Streets.MinimumPrefixLength = 2;
  AutoCompleteBox_Streets.Populating += AutoComplete_Populating;
}

private async void AutoComplete_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e) {
   // e.Parameter will contain the chars in your textbox.
   AutoCompleteBox_Streets.ItemsSource = 
       await GetStreets(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Parameter));
   AutoCompleteBox_Streets.PopulateComplete();
}

private async Task<List<string>> GetStreets(string chars) {
  JObject jo = new JObject();
  jo.Add("chars", chars);
  // Rest of your method code
  // ...
}
```

---

What you need is setting `MinimumPrefixLength` property to 2.

Also move your bindings to the constructor and remove the `TextChanged` event.

```cs
// Your constructor
public MyPage() {
  InitializeComponent();
  BindStreetNames();
}

private async void BindStreetNames() {
  AutoCompleteBox_Streets.ItemsSource = await GetStreets();
  AutoCompleteBox_Streets.MinimumPrefixLength = 2;
}

private async void AutoCompleteBox_Streets_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  /* Remove this handler */
}
```

Comment: I need to get list of streets from server **only** after I entered two characters. I tried to use MinimumPrefixLength, but it didn't help.

Comment: Making a web request call in your TextChanged event is not advisable. You need to take into consideration that the remote call might take varying time depending on network condition making the possibility of meeting your requirement very slim. The code above will pop the list after 2 characters has been entered.

Comment: I need to send two characters in my request. Only if i send two characters, i can get responce. So I nedd to call, GetSteets, after I enterd two characters.