# How to use AutoCompleteBox with MVVM Light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to figure out how the best way to use AutoCompleteBox with MVVM Light.

```
    public ICommand AutoComplete
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(e =>
                {
                    var txtBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;

                    if (e.Key == Key.Unknown)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    string autoComplete = txtBox.Text + e.Key;

                    if (autoComplete.Length >= 3)
                    {
                        RestClient c = new RestClient("http://localhost:3333/api/store");
                        RestRequest r = new RestRequest("/GetStoreNames",Method.GET);
                        r.AddParameter("Name", autoComplete);
                        r.AddParameter("Latitude", "49");
                        r.AddParameter("Longitude", "49");
                        var d =  c.BuildUri(r);
                        c.ExecuteAsync(r, response2 =>
                          {
                              var content = response2.Content;
                          });
                    }


                });
            }
        }


    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AutoComplete, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>


<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acbStore" Margin="154,196,29,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.6,0.083" Height="162" MinimumPopulateDelay="500"/>
```

I did the above but there is a couple problems.

Once I get the results back how do I show them in the auto complete area?

How can I delay it from doing to many requests at once? As you can see I don't want to hit the server before 3 characters are entered but after that it is fair game. I am kinda worried that like 20 requests will be done to the server before the 1st request makes it back leading to wasted bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `KeyDown` event or similar? That is not the way you want to do it. Instead, bind the `AutoCompleteBox` `Populating` event and set the `MinimumPrefixLength` on your `AutoCompleteBox` to 3 so that`Populating` is fired only when you have 3+ characters. To show the list retrieved in your control, the list need to be bound to `ItemsSource` property then a method needs to be called, `PopulateComeplte()`.

You can see my answer here on a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842731/dont-show-dropdown-in-autocompletebox-in-windows-phone/16846463#16846463).

However, it is not MVVM friendly since you need to call a method on your `AutoCompleteBox` to trigger the control to show the list from your webservice. Take a look at this [article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-AutoCompleteBox.aspx) for a MVVM-friendly approach, scroll down to "Bonus: MVVM-friendly asynchronous filtering" section.

Comment: Ya sorry thought it showed the keyDown event but ya I am using that. I will check that out and see how it goes.